# What is difference between lcuda and lcudart in CUDA SDK 7.5?

Tags: linux, cuda, clang

I have Nvidea SDK 7.5. I want to [compile OpenMP for CUDA](https://parallel-computing.pro/index.php/9-cuda/43-openmp-4-0-on-nvidia-cuda-gpus). On step "Clone, build & install OpenMP target backends" I get:
[image]

Yet I see no libcuda.lib at all in my SDK:
[image]

So I wonder what is difference between lcuda and lcudart and if there is any where one can find lcuda in CUDA 7.5 SDK?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `l` you are discussing in "lcuda" and "lcudart" is actually part of the compiler switch.  The library is `cuda` or `libcuda`, and `cudart` or `libcudart`.

On linux, I don't think these libraries end in `.lib` either.  They should end in `.so`  That's pretty evident in your printout - take a look.

Anyway, libcuda.so is installed by the GPU *driver installer*, not the toolkit.

(except possibly for stubs, which you should not use) libcuda.so will not be found in the toolkit location but somewhere else where the driver puts it. This particular location will vary depending on the specific linux distro.

So I suggest using `find` or a similar linux command to locate it on your machine.  It may be in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` or someplace like that.

If you can't find it at all, then the likely explanation is that you have not installed (properly) the GPU driver on your machine.

In a nutshell, libcuda.so provides access to the [CUDA driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#axzz47jvPSd6r), whereas libcudart.so provides access to the [CUDA runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#axzz47jvPSd6r).

By the way, in the future,  please post text output, not pictures, for actual text output from your console.

Comment: could not find `libcuda.so` nowhere in `/usr/`. Is there any option of asking `nvcc` where it is located?

Comment: no, `nvcc` won't locate it for you.  Is linux `find` not an option?  Something like this:  `sudo find / -name libcudart*`   If that doesn't find anything, then it is not installed, and that indicates a broken driver install.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `sudo find / -name libcuda.*`.  And when I do that on a properly installed ppc64le node with RHEL 7, I observe that the GPU driver has placed the `libcuda.so` at: `/usr/lib/nvidia/libcuda.so` and also at `/usr/lib/libcuda.so`